# Dividing images into parts

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage, xor

i am doing XOR of pixel values using the following code

```
BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(new File(1.bmp));
BufferedImage img = new  BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(),bi.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

int[] pixel;

for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
        pixel = bi.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[3]);
        img.setRGB(x, y, col);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn these values into parameters - the two 0s and the height, width.

```
for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
```

Changed it would look like this.

```
for (int y = y0; y < y1; y++) {
    for (int x = x0; x < x1; x++) {
```

Now turn this into a function/method and make 4 calls to it passing these values.

1. `y0=0; y1=bi.getHeight()/2; x0=0; x1=bi.getWidth()/2`
2. `y0=bi.getHeight()/2 + 1; y1=bi.getHeight(); x0=0; x1=bi.getWidth()/2`
3. `y0=0; y1=bi.getHeight()/2; x0=bi.getWidth()/2+1; x1=bi.getWidth()`
4. `y0=bi.getHeight()/2 + 1; y1=bi.getHeight(); x0=bi.getWidth()/2+1; x1=bi.getWidth()`

Comment: @Ramya Not sure what you mean by this. Maybe you could elaborate.

Comment: @Ramya Well, maybe you can start 4 separate threads, once they are all done, you combine their outputs. But... I am not sure your idea is valid i.e. not sure if it will have the desired performance effect. That would depend on many other factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getData(Ractangle rect) to return a region. Check it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)